# Odoo change name occurence in pages and menus

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to change the displayed name Vendors in the Purchase application. I was successful in changing the submenu name from Settings--> Technical--> User interface(menu items). Now when i select this submenu the page that gets displayed has 'Vendors' displayed on the left top and in the filters. How do i change Vendors to some other name wherever it occurs.

I am using odoo 12

Answer (score 2):

there are two methods, 
the simplest is to change the name for each action view (form, tree). See the photos

the second, the same thing but by editing the xml of action code by inheriting the targeted view in order to modify it.

i hope that's can help you

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok i tried this , it updated the top left Title to the changed name.Thanks. How do i change 'Vendors' at other places, like the filter. Do you have a link or something for the second method (xml)?

Comment: For the second method, you should create a module where inhérite the action you want to edit, to do that you have to learn about how to create odoo module.